# Why I am not getting welcome mail when I add new Member(Profile) to communities and when I published community

Tags: community

I am not getting any welcome emails when i published my community.

Steps I followed for Community user creation.

1. Contact created--> From contact details page "Manage External User"--> Selected Enable    Customer User.

   2.Selected "Customer Community" as User License and Selected "Customer Community User" as User Profile.
   3.Entered Email address and Username values and Deselected Generate Password check box.
   4.Saved the user information.

Add Member to the communities:
1. Edit the community and Member--> select "Customer Community User" Profile to add member list.
2. Then Saved and Email--> Checked Welcome mail Check Box.
3. Then Published Community.

These steps i followed for Community configuration.

But I am not get any welcome mails and reset password link mails.

Please guide me where i did mistake.

Thanks,
Yarram

Comment: Is this a Sandbox?

Comment: No, Developer Edition

Answer (score 2):

I would check your email deliverability settings, and make sure they are set to All email.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I did that "All email" Configuration also. actually I am using Developer Edition, is there any problem with Developer Edition?

Comment: I have done it with Developer Edition orgs, did you also verify your email addresses are correct in the DE org?  One last thing, would be to look at the Email Log Files to see if it shows the messages going out or not.

Comment: Yes, I have verified my Email log files it showing DNS cloumn like this message "550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender". Do you have any idea about this Permission? How to give the Permissions?

Comment: Sounds like there is a setting in your email server that is preventing the mail.  Did you configure an Org wide email address, or something like that?  You might also try running the "Test Deliverability" check in the Email administration.  Maybe your email server will not accept inbound email from the developer org.

Answer (score 2):

Acctivate the Customer Portal. Administration > Settings > Status ... make it activate.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of steps looks correct. You may want to double check that A) your users are correctly associated with the 'Customer Community User' profile which you used while setting up the community. B) you published the community as the last step after adding the users associated with the correct profile. Also, check This [tutorial](http://www.bluewolf.com/blog/getting-started-salesforce-communities) to see if you missed anything.

If the issue is still not resolved, you may want to test by enabling the 'Allow users to self-register' option and test if that works - just to ensure that your community is actually setup correctly with the right configuration.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply I have tested this option also but still i am not getting welcome mails. Is there any other way to configure this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are facing the "550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender" error, can you confirm which email server are you using?

This is a SMTP error which you usually get when you don't have the 'Send As' permission configured on youe mail account. Check the "Send As" permission on your mail server to allow your agent accounts to send email as your outbound mailbox account and I believe that should fix it.

Refer [this](https://support.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/1104707-client-does-not-have-permissions-to-send-as-this-sender-error-) link for more details and on how you can set this permission for various types of mail servers